# I get error on live site after Preparse-field update

Tags: plugins

After I've turned devMode on live site to see what's going on a **fatal error appeared:** Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/craft/plugins/preparsefield/PreparseFieldPlugin.php on line 112

The weird thing is, that with same settings on local machine it runs as expected.

Comment: What PHP versions are you running locally and on the live site?

Comment: I'm going to update from 5.3.3 to latest stable and check it again. I'm running 7.0.0 localy.

Comment: The update did the job. But odd part is until Preparse-field update my previous server config (PHP 5.3.3) was able to create record to preparse field without any problems. But thanks you @Andre Elvan for pointing out to PHP version. I haven't thought of that because of no running problems from before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to version 0.3.0 breaking PHP 5.3 support. A fix has been implemented in 0.3.1 that fixes this.